# Finding the specific column (field) name from multiple tables in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have large numbers of tables in my database. I am searching for a column named `Country`, but don't know which table contains that column. Is there a specific query that will help me to find the name of the table containing this column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   TABLE_NAME 
FROM 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'Country'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%ColumnName%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Replace `ColumnName` to your actual column name

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct table_schema, table_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'Country';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find such of information in the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx)

```
USE YourDBName;
SELECT DISTINCT Table_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE Column_Name = 'Country';
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to find a column name with like operator in more than one tables (ex: 3 tables) then go for below query:

```
select COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME in ('SIL_RLS_UPLOAD_TMP','SIL_CUSTOMER_MST','SIL_PERSONAL_CUSTOMER_MST')
      and upper(column_name) like upper('%loan%');
```

If we want to find a column name with like operator in all tables then go for below query:

```
select * 
from all_tab_columns 
where upper(column_name) like upper('%card%');
```